# Spring Boot - deploy .properties file to a folder different than 'WEB-INF/classes'

Tags: spring-boot, war, web-inf

I'm trying to convert a traditional Tomcat Spring MVC webapp to Spring Boot. The new application should still use .war deployment.

For various reasons I have the obligatory requirement that the `application.properties` file resides inside a `WEB-INF/conf` folder in the deployed app and NOT inside the `WEB-INF/classes` folder where Spring Boot puts it by default.

In the original webapp I could put the `application.properties` file inside the `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/conf` folder (so they get copied to `WEB-INF/conf` in the deployed application) and then use it like this:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/conf/application.properties"/>
```

What is the Spring Boot way to refer to this location?

I tried adding each of the following:

```
spring.config.location=WEB-INF/conf/application.properties
```

but my `application.properties` file still doesn't get loaded.

Comment: remove the `webapp` part... The file is still at the same location. But still if it is part of the war why should the location matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally worked was the following `@PropertySource` annotation.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(value = {"WEB-INF/conf/application.properties"})
public class MyApplication {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

It seems that not specifying `classpath:` or `file:` at the beginning of a path makes it use a path relative to the webapp.

I'm still not sure as to why specifying

```
spring.config.location=WEB-INF/conf/application.properties
```

didn't have the same effect.